# remove all inline css from html tags only exception is not to remove display:none propety

Tags: php, preg-replace

want to remove all css rules from inline css but not to remove display none property

for example,

```
 <p style="color:red;display:none;float:left;">
```

I Tried this I am using php simple HTML DOM parser

and snippet is here

```
 foreach ($obj->find('img') as $e) {
        $imgSrc = $e -> src;
        preg_match_all('~' . SITE_NAME . '~is', $imgSrc, $match);
        if (count($match[0]) == 0) {
            $loadedSrcs = SITE_NAME . $imgSrc;
        } else {
            $loadedSrcs = $imgSrc;
        }

        $currentImageSrc = $e -> outertext;
        $replacementImageSrc = "src='" . $loadedSrcs . "'";
        $changeSrc = preg_replace('/src=[\'|\"][^\'|\"]*[\'|\"]/is', $replacementImageSrc, $currentImageSrc);
        //$imageSrc = "<img src=".$changeSrc." />";

       $ImagesWithFullPath = preg_replace('~<img [^c]*c=[\'|\"]'.$e -> src.'[^\>]*\>~is', $changeSrc , $ImagesWithFullPath);

    // now I want to remove diffrent style property from Image and wandering how could I write the preg_replace not display:none 

}
```

Hope it helps to understand my Query

I want to do it with preg_replace(php) not with Jquery.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: strip the whole paragraph tag an insert a new one: `<p style="display: none;">`

Comment: [Don't try parsing HTML with regexps.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Use a [proper HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) instead.

Comment: I tried with preg_replace but stuck

Comment: just put an if condition if (1) <p style="color:red;display:none;float:left;"> else <p style="display:none">

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen I already usinf PHP SIMPLE DOM PARSER I am Posting my code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the proper element with an HTML parser:

```
$styles = array_map('trim', explode(';', $e->style));
if (in_array('display:none', $styles)) {
    $e->style='display:none';
}
else {
    $e->style='';
}
```